# Join two observables with flatMap - Angular2

Tags: angular, reactjs, rxjs, observable

i have two observables

```
 getProfile(nickname: string, server: string): Observable<Profile> {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/summoners?name='+ nickname + '&server=' + server )
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .map((res: Object) => new Profile().from(res));
}
```

this model

```
export class Profile {

public id: number;
public accountId: number;
public name: string;
public summonerLevel: number;
```

and the second one is

```
export class League {

public name: string;
public tier: string;
public queue: string;
public entries: LeaguePlayer[] = [];
```

so, I want to join these two observables into one, I know I need to use flatMap to do this, but I don't know how do this.
I've tried to do

```
getProfileWithLeagues(nickname: string, server: string): Observable<Profile> {
return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/summoners?name='+ nickname + '&server=' + server)
  .map(response => response.json().data as Profile)
  .flatMap((profiles: Profile) => Observable.forkJoin(profiles.map((summoner: Profile) => {
      return this.getLeagues(summoner.id, server)
        .map((leagues: League) => {
          summoner.leagues.from(leagues);
          return summoner;
        });
    }))
   );
 }
```

but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong, what can I do to do what I want? thanks for all :)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  Some context on what you are seeing when you debug would be helpful.

Comment: @jonnysai's is where I would start.  It appears that you never subscribe to the flatmap observable.  The forkjoin appears unnecessary.

Comment: this code return just de Profile, withou de leagues, and I need to join this two objects in another one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try some thing like this

```
getProfileWithLeagues(nickname: string, server: string): Observable<Profile> {
return Observable.flatMap(data => {
            return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/summoners?name='+ nickname + '&server=' + server)
  .map(response => response.json().data as Profile);
}).subscribe((profiles: Profile) => {
  // write your code
 } );
 }
```

I didn't understand your full code but you can start like this.